# Selecting Button element with webdriver-selenium in nodejs

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, selenium-webdriver

I have an html page for posting data to server, i need to select specific button for automating job

```html
   <div id="cdk-overlay-17" class="cdk-overlay-pane" style="max-width: position: static;">
    <div tabindex="0" class="cdk-visually-hidden cdk-focus-trap-anchor"></div>
    <mat-dialog-container aria-modal="true" class="mat-dialog-container ng-tns-c21-58 ng-trigger ng-trigger-dialogContainer ng-star-inserted" tabindex="-1" id="mat-dialog-17" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mat-dialog-title-17" style="transform: none;">
        <!---->
        <app-pin-dialog class="ng-star-inserted">
            <button class="modal-close-button" mat-dialog-close="" type="button" hidden="" title="name1" aria-label="Close dialog"></button>
            <h2 class="mat-dialog-title" mat-dialog-title="" id="mat-dialog-title-17">name2</h2>
            <mat-dialog-content class="mat-typography mat-dialog-content">
                <p class="description">name2</p>
                <div class="form">
                    <app-input form-name="code" has-content="" max-length="6" required="" type="password">
                        <!---->
                        <div class="form-group ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-star-inserted has-error ng-touched" style="">
                            <!---->
                            <div class="form-control ng-star-inserted">
                                <input type="password" name="code" placeholder="PIN" maxlength="6" class="ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-touched">
                            </div>
                            <!---->
                            <div class="form-error ng-star-inserted">
                                <!---->
                                <div class="ng-star-inserted">name3</div>
                                <!---->
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </app-input>
                </div>
            </mat-dialog-content>
            <mat-dialog-actions align="center" class="mat-dialog-actions">
                <ul class="button-group">
                    <li>
                        <button class="btn btn-navy" mat-dialog-close="" type="button" aria-label="Close dialog">text1</button>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <button class="btn btn-blue" type="button">text2</button>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </mat-dialog-actions>
        </app-pin-dialog>
    </mat-dialog-container>
    <div tabindex="0" class="cdk-visually-hidden cdk-focus-trap-anchor"></div>
    </div>
```

I am trying to select "text2" with selenium

```
      (await driver).findElement(By.className("cdk-overlay-pane btn btn-blue")).click();
```

but it fails:

```
      Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"cdk-overlay-pane btn btn-blue"}
```

also tried

```
 (await driver).findElement(By.className("btn btn-blue")).click();
```

failed again.
How should i select ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Root cause is there is not element that have the `cdk-overlay-pane btn btn-blue` in the source. Instead element with `btn btn-blue` class is in the div with `cdk-overlay-pane` class. So you have to use `By.css` in this case as you are pointing to the element using `css`. please use the `By.className` only when you are locating the element with `class` of destination element.

**Note:** 
you **don't** have to explicitly replace the white spaces between classes in the element `class` with `.` as the selenium code it take care of this.

Ex:

`findElement(By.className('btn.btn-blue'))`  - **correct**

`findElement(By.className('btn btn-blue'))`  - **correct**

`findElement(By.className('.btn.btn-blue'))`  - **Wrong (as selenium will prepend `.` to the className sent here)**

Here is the logic used by selenium for your reference.

```
static className(name) {
    let names = name.split(/\s+/g)
        .filter(s => s.length > 0)
        .map(s => escapeCss(s));
    return By.css('.' + names.join('.'));
  }
```

*Source* [SeleniumHQ](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/javascript/node/selenium-webdriver/lib/by.js#L116)

So, you can try with the below.

```
(await driver).findElement(By.css(".cdk-overlay-pane .btn.btn-blue")).click();
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: it failed also like { "cdk-overlay-pane\.btn\.btn-blue" }

Comment: Please check the updated answer. If still if you are getting `NoSuchElement Exception` please check if the element is wrapped in iframe.

Comment: @trmt please find the detailed explanation in the updated answer. Let me know if you still have any questions.